# Why is my List.Contains not working?

Tags: c#, string, list, contains

For some reason, my code below isnt working. I have confirmed that there is both .idx and .log files within the folder. Can someone please help?

Thanks.

```
List<string> subDirList = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(srcPath, "*"));

if (subDirList.Contains(".idx") && subDirList.Contains(".log"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The first thing you do should be to look at the contents of `subDirList`.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I have confirmed that .idx and .log both exist in the contents. I cant post screenshots on here as my reputation is not high enough yet, but the strings are both in subDirList.

Comment: Most likely, you won't have two files with *exactly* the names `".idx"` and `".log"`. Instead, you'll want to check if you can find two files whose *file names* contain `.idx` and `.log`.

Comment: I might be answering my own question here, but does List.Contains need to match the entire Line of the List<string> ? Or just a part of it? Because the entire line is something like "C:\Temp\Test\file1.log" and "C:\Temp\Test\file2.idx". Would this return true from List.Contains(".log") ?

Comment: No. `Contains` on `List<string>` requires the entire string to match.

Comment: `List.Contains` checks if a list *contains* the given object, that is if there is an element which is *equal* to the given object (in this case, a `string`). `string.Contains` checks if a string *contains* the given substring. They are two very different methods, working with very different data. You're looking for some kind of combination of these two, which you can do with `Any` (which is a more general form of `Contains`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`subDirList` contains filenames, not only extensions. That's why you're finding nothing.

You should probably use `Any` with `EndsWith`:

```
if (subDirList.Any(x => x.EndsWith(".idx")) && subDirList.Any(x => x.EndsWith(".log")))
```

Or if `.idx` and `.log` are not extensions, but just part of filename, use `Contains`:

```
if (subDirList.Any(x => x.Contains(".idx")) && subDirList.Any(x => x.Contains(".log")))
```